How to rollback to a specific dialog during installation in setup project - visual studio
I have an installer made using setup project in which I used a textbox dialog which asks for a installation key and the installation should further proceed only after entering the correct key.
To achieve this, I have written a dll code in c++ which is placed as a custom action under "Install" and the properties are set as follows
properties of dll set under install custom action
Code written in dll goes like this
UINT __stdcall Install(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
    
    TCHAR szValue[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD dwSize = MAX_PATH;

    // Retrieve the value entered in the textbox
    if (MsiGetProperty(hInstall, TEXT("EDITA1"), szValue, &dwSize) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
    }
    else {
        if (lstrcmp(szValue, TEXT("hello world")) == 0) {
            return ERROR_SUCCESS;
        }
        else {
          MessageBox(NULL, _T("Incorrect installation key!"), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR |       MB_TOPMOST);
            return ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE; 
          }
            
     }
    
    
}

what is this doing?
Upon entering the installation key, installation proceeds, validating key and if wrong, message is shown.This is exiting the installation after clicking ok but I want to roll back to textbox dialog for entering the key again.
one more thing to add, message box although placed as MB_TOPMOST, it is seen as another taskbar icon and I have to press icon to see the message. It is not visible/ popped up as message
Note: I dont want to use any of the third party toolsets to achieve this
Can someone help me with this?
